# LayoutInflater in android

Tags: android

When I use layoutInflater in android to create custom layout in list then at the declaration of `LayoutInflater` give an error unreachable statement . How fix it

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_custom , parent,false);

        Tour tour = tours.get(position);
        TextView tv =(TextView) vw.findViewById(R.id.texttile);
        tv.setText(tour.getTitle());

       tv =(TextView) vw.findViewById(R.id.price);
        NumberFormat nf= NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        tv.setText(nf.format(tour.getPrice()));

        ImageView iv  =(ImageView) vw.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        int imageResource  = context.getResources().getIdentifier(tour.getImage() , "drawable" , context.getPackageName());
        if (imageResource!=0){
            iv.setImageResource(imageResource);
        }
        return  vw;
    }
```

`LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` says unreachble statement

Comment: you see that `return` statement?

Comment: it's exactly what the warning says.

Comment: It will execute the return line and exit the method. Simply place your code before return statement.

Comment: It's the ABC of programming: `Every method should have only a single exit point`

Answer (score 2):

Problem for your

```
  return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

Remove this **`return`**.

Actually wrong **`return`** statement creates **un-reachable statement**.

> We don't put return statement above any other statement unless that
>   return is under any conditional statement.

Courtesy goes to

> [I get the error "Unreachable statement" return in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102614/i-get-the-error-unreachable-statement-return-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

remove line
return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

Comment: You have  [Comment Everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege. Why are you adding everything as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

***REMOVE return keyword**
after removing

```
super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping at StackOverflow. The answer is basically correct and constructive, but needs some rephrasing for clarity and readability.